# Select the latest hour for rates

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have this scenario where I need to get the exchange rate for several coin pairs. I have 2 tables, one with info related to a bank operation and another with the daily exchange rates considered by the bank. I'm starting to learn about data analytic, so be patient please. My english not that great also.

Consider this example:

Table 1 (Bank Operations):

```
Op Number | Coin_1 | Coin_2 | Date       | Hour 1  | Weekday |
    1     | EUR    | GBP    | 2020/06/01 | 03:30   | Monday  |
```

Table 2 (Exchange rates):

```
Coin_1 | Coin_2 | Date           | Hour 2     | Weekday  | Rate 
EUR    | GBP    |   2020/03/01   |  11:30     | Friday   | 0.6
EUR    | GBP    |   2020/03/01   |  18:30     | Friday   | 0.5
EUR    | GBP    |   2020/06/01   |  12:30     | Monday   | 0.55
```

Note: The exchange rates are not actualized on weekends.

I do not know how will I get this value. Using a script component? If so can you help me with the algorithm? I've done all the ETL needed this far, but can't seem to find a workaround for this task.

Comment: Table 2 is exchange rates at a given point in time and Table 1 is transactions that you need to pin to the nearest previous exchange rate period, yes?

Comment: Exactly @billinkc

Comment: Are both tables in the same SQL Server database? And what version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: Both tables are in the same database. I'm working locally and using SQL server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a learning exercise, great use the componentry of SSIS to do it. If this is real world stuff, trust my experience on this, trying to use the SSIS pieces to make this happen will not be pleasant.

One of the bigger challenges in your existing data model is that you store date and time separately. I assume that the source system stores it as a date and time(0) data types. I create an actual datetime2 column in my queries so that I can leverage the fine engineers at Microsoft to worry about getting comparison logic correct.

Instead of a lead/lag solution as Steve proposes, I saw this as an [OUTER APPLY with TOP 1 problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da0fddc4fa148d277e772082ba40542d).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.BankOperations
(
    CaseNumber int
,   Coin_1 char(3)
,   Coin_2 char(3)
,   TransactionDate date
,   TransactionTime time(0)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ExchangeRates
(
    CaseNumber int
,   Coin_1 char(3)
,   Coin_2 char(3)
,   TransactionDate date
,   TransactionTime time(0)
,   Rate decimal(4, 2)
);

INSERT INTO
    dbo.BankOperations
VALUES
(
    1, 'EUR', 'GBP', '2020-06-01', '03:30'
)
-- boundary checking exact
,( 2, 'EUR', 'GBP', '2020-06-01', '12:30')
-- boundary beyond/not defined
,( 3, 'EUR', 'GBP', '2020-06-01', '13:30')
-- boundary before
,( 4, 'EUR', 'GBP', '2020-03-01', '10:30')
-- boundary first at
,( 5, 'EUR', 'GBP', '2020-03-01', '11:30')

INSERT INTO
    dbo.ExchangeRates
VALUES
(
    1, 'EUR', 'GBP', '2020-03-01', '11:30', .6
)
, (
      2, 'EUR', 'GBP', '2020-03-01', '18:30', .5
  )
, (
      3, 'EUR', 'GBP', '2020-06-01', '12:30', .55
  );

-- Creating a temp table version of the above as the separate date and time fields will 
-- crush performance at scale (so too might duplicating data as we're about to do)
SELECT
    X.*
,   CAST(CONCAT(X.TransactionDate, 'T', X.TransactionTime) AS datetime2(0)) AS IsThisWorking
INTO
    #BankOperations
FROM
    dbo.BankOperations AS X;

SELECT
    X.*
,   CAST(CONCAT(X.TransactionDate, 'T', X.TransactionTime) AS datetime2(0)) AS IsThisWorking
INTO
    #ExchangeRates
FROM
    dbo.ExchangeRates AS X;


-- Option A for pinning data 
-- Outer apply will show use the TOP 1 to get the closest without going over
SELECT
BO.*
  -- assuming surrogate key
, EX.CaseNumber
, EX.Rate
FROM
    #BankOperations AS BO
    OUTER APPLY
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM
        #ExchangeRates AS ER
    WHERE
        -- Match based on all of our keys
        ER.Coin_1 = BO.Coin_1
        AND ER.Coin_2 = BO.Coin_2
        -- Eliminate
        AND BO.IsThisWorking >= ER.IsThisWorking 
    ORDER BY
        ER.IsThisWorking DESC
    )EX
;

-- Option B
-- Use lead/lag function to get the value
-- but my brain isn't seeing it at the moment
/*
SELECT
BO.*
  -- assuming surrogate key
,   LAG()
FROM
    #BankOperations AS BO
    INNER JOIn #ExchangeRates

*/
```

If I were forced to provide a purely SSIS based answer, I'd use the Lookup Component and rather than the default FULL Cache, I'd operate it in None. The performance implication is that for every row that enters the buffer, we are going to fire off a query to the source system to retrieve the one row of data. Depending on volume, this may be "heavy."

As a source, you have an OLE DB Source component pointed at BankOperations. That flows into a Lookup which we'll parameterize.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM
    dbo.ExchangeRates AS ER
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(CONCAT(ER.TransactionDate, 'T', ER.TransactionTime) AS datetime2(0)) AS IsThisWorking) ITW
WHERE
    -- Match based on all of our keys
    ER.Coin_1 = ?
    AND ER.Coin_2 = ?
    -- Eliminate what's too new
    AND CAST(CONCAT(?, 'T', ?) AS datetime2(0)) >= ITW.IsThisWorking 
ORDER BY
    ITW.IsThisWorking DESC
```

All the ? in there are ordinal specific place holders, starting at 0. What we're looking to do is mimic the logic of the original query. Full disclosure, it's been ages since I've done a parameterized none/partial cache lookup so some of the finer points you'll have to read up on. What I do remember is that you'll be clicking on advanced "stuff" to get this to work.

A different approach I've seen using SSIS componentry will involve two sources and an join. I think it was [Matt Masson](https://www.mattmasson.com/tag/ssis/) who demoed this technique but it's been years since I've had to do it. Again, you'll have better performance if you do this in your source query as this approach will require two sorts + the blocking transform of a Join.

The best Script Component approach is going to take emulate the parameterized Lookup component approach. It remains Synchronous (1 row in, 1 row out) and we'd enrich the data flow by adding our Rate column.

Psuedocode approximately

```
// make local variables with values from the row buffer
var coin_1 = Row.coin1;
var coin_2 = Row.coin2;
var transactionDate = Row.IsThisWorking;

// standard OLE DB parameterized query stuff here
using (SqlConnection conn = new SQLConnection)
{
    conn.Open();
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.Text = "SELECT TOP 1 ER.Rate FROM dbo.ExchangeRate AS ER WHERE @txnDate >= ER.IsThisWorking AND ER.Coin_1 = @coin1 AND ER.Coin_2 = @coin2;";
        // I don't remember exact syntax
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txnDate", transactionDate);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coin1", coin_1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coin2", coin_2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dunno how to thank you @billinkc! Amazing explanation! Really opened my eyes to some matters I need to adress. I tried the first approach and it worked smoothly. I will try the other 2 and compare performances :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in sql using the [lead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) windowing functions and some datetime maths.

```
create table #t1(
  [Case] int,
  [Op Number] int,
  [Coin_1] varchar(10),
  [Coin_2] varchar(10),
  [Date] date,
  [Hour 1] time,
  [Weekday] varchar(10)
)

insert into #t1 values 
( 1, 1, 'EUR', 'GBP', '2020/06/01', '03:30', 'Monday')

create table #t2(
  [Case] int,
  [Coin_1] varchar(10),
  [Coin_2] varchar(10),
  [Date] date,
  [Hour 2] time,
  [Weekday] varchar(10),
  [Rate] decimal(10,2)
)

insert into #t2 values 
( 1, 'EUR', 'GBP', '2020/03/01', '11:30', 'Friday', 0.6),
( 1, 'EUR', 'GBP', '2020/03/01', '18:30', 'Friday', 0.5 ),
( 1, 'EUR', 'GBP', '2020/06/01', '12:30', 'Monday', 0.55)

; with t1 as (
  select *, dt =  CAST(CONCAT([Date], ' ', [hour 1]) AS datetime2(0)) 
  from #t1
)
, x as (
  select *, dt =  CAST(CONCAT([Date], ' ', [hour 2]) AS datetime2(0)) 
  from #t2
)
, t2 as (
  select [Case],
    [Coin_1],
    [Coin_2],
    [Rate],
    [Date]
    [Hour 2],
    [Weekday],
    dt as start_dt,
    isnull(lead(dt) over(partition by [case] order by dt asc), '20990101') end_dt
  from x
)

select *
from t1
inner join t2 on t2.[case] = t1.[case]          
              and t1.dt >= t2.start_dt
              and t1.dt < t2.end_dt
```

Comment: I really need to use SSIS on this one. Is it possible to use a script component or a SQL task to perform this? The solution must be automatized. But still, you've teached me something really useful, so thank you for that. The case column was just for simplification, I do not have it

Comment: You could use the sql and perform the joining in ssis or you could create a Cartesian join between T1 and T2 and then use a asynchronous script component to produce an output buffer when the ordered collection has found the appropriate row. This would be done by creating the datetime object in c# and returning the previous row values where the previous row had a datetime less than or equal to t2.datetime and the current row has a datetime greater that the datetime of T1.

Comment: will try the first approach. The second one seems too complex for my level of knowledge. Thank you!